# A space of a different width?

Tags: html, character, space

I can effectively create a two column layout in a `<select>` by using JavaScript to measure the text and add the appropriate number of spaces. However, depending on the font size, the space is ~4 pixels in width, meaning the [column on the right kinda wavers](http://jsfiddle.net/cBb9z/) to the left or the right up to 3 pixels at a time.

`Fixed width` is not the solution. Wavering actually looks better in this case. But an alternate space would be even better.

Is there a space of a different width that I can calculate in to reduce the waver?

Comment: Why would you try to have two columns in a `select` box?

Comment: Can you put this up in a fiddle? It sounds insane.

Comment: @zzzzBov: to show two different pieces of information I would imagine.

Comment: @Mathletics, [Here you go!](http://jsfiddle.net/cBb9z/) Note that in the real world, JavaScript would handle the alignments, and if the alternate space was wider than normal, it would take advantage of that in order to remove the left-right jitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various fixed-width spaces, but they do not work consistently across fonts.

If you need tabular presentation, use a table. This means that instead of a `select` element, you would use a set of radio buttons. You can then divide the radio button labels in two columns (and put the radio buttons in a column of their own, perhaps).

Comment: They do not need to work consistently across fonts. JavaScript will detect the differences in width and take advantage if possible. I would rather know one or more space characters I can use, than to just get an answer to switch to tables.

Comment: You can find information about fixed-width spaces in the Unicode standard, but you will find out that they do not work consistently across fonts and that this is a real problem. To begin with, most fonts do not contain most of them.

Comment: If the font does not contain the character, then it is a problem, but if the width is different depending on which font is used, JavaScript will detect it. I found a list here http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html